# Is there a standard Control for creating an in-app video player?

Tags: windows-phone-7, media-player, mediaelement

Im making a videoplayer in a wp7 app. Im using mediaelement to show the video, and sets its source from a url. Functionality i wanted are play/stop-buttons, forwarding/rewinding, a progressindicator (for the progress of the video itself) and show a progressbar when it buffers. I have accomplished all above, using some customized grids, buttons and so on.
I did get some trouble though, which i dont want to bother you with here (its a mess) and which is why im asking the following:

Is there a standard (or downloadable) control for wp7 that does all these things for me and that works perfectly. Ive searched "everywhere" but couldnt find anything. It surprises me that this isnt an easy to use, built in control that is easy to customize, since standard videoplayers are something id guess alot of apps could take advantage of.

Anyone?

Comment: many app use the built-in MediaPlayerLauncher which does all that you need but cannot be embeded into a page, runs in its own window

Comment: Thats of great help, thanks! Do you know if its colors, buttons etc are customizable?

Comment: I do not think it is customizable at all

Answer (score 2):

Here is a tutorial on how to create a [Windows Phone 7 View Model Style Video Player](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/84859/Windows-Phone-7-View-Model-Style-Video-Player).

Comment: Thanks, thats not far from what ive already done though. Its a long tutorial! Alot of work to make almost the same as i already have. Think m gonna try the easy way of using mediaplayerlauncher first, and this as a last resort if nothing else does the job.

Comment: The good thing about this tutorial is that it is developped in an MVVM  way

Comment: yeah, and thats a big plus. Im developing (or atleast trying to) the mvvm way, but im probably doing something wrong somewhere